# How to scroll to bottom of page using JavaScript when accordion control is used in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, accordion

I want to scroll down to a text box control which is nested in accordion in ASP.NET. I have tried using AccordionExtender followed by the below script.

```
function validate() {
 if (condition){alert("Provide Recommendations under Closing Details before closing a story.");

 window.setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById('<%=txtrec.ClientID%>').focus();
                }, 0);
         ScrollToBottom();

return false;
}

}

    function ScrollToBottom() {
                window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
            }



<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return validate()" />&nbsp;
```

** I have "txtrec" control in accordion.

Comment: FYI Java is a language and it is very different from JavaScript (which is what you are asking about.)

Comment: she/he wrote `Java Script` not `Java` and he pointed it out from the start in his tags...

Comment: Does that.. not work? Also have you tried putting a console log inside your `ScrollToBottom` function to be sure it's actually getting fired?

Comment: I have checked using an alert message inside my function. i can see it is getting fired. I suspect accordion control is stopping it from scrolling down.

Comment: Can you post your aspx code please?